# Is FCM (Firebase cloud messaging) support directboot?

Tags: android

We have an android application using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) and we would like to ensure that all push notifications to be received when device was rebooted and before unlocking the screen (directboot situation).

For Pixel XL device, the push notification were received only after the screen was unlocked (which behaves differently than Galaxy S8).

For Pixel XL device, the following errors and warnings were observed in Logcat console:

```
11-07 14:45:33.331 1574-1758/? E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.contextmanager.service.ContextManagerService.START on com.google.android.gms
11-07 14:45:33.334 922-1525/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.contextmanager.service.ContextManagerService.START pkg=com.google.android.gms } U=0: not found
11-07 14:45:33.336 922-1497/? W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@19bf522
```

Please help if you have successfully implemented FCM push notification for directboot or experienced the same issue before.

Answer (score 1):

##### Update 2022-06:

According to FCM documentation it now support messages in DirectBoot:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#receive_fcm_messages_in_direct_boot_mode

##### Original answer:

On a recently closed Google+ there is a comment about it: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Q5iTa8Gyffd
[image: Google+ screenshot]

Comment above as a text:

> none of Google Play services is currently available while the device
> is locked - you'll need to wait for the device to be unlocked before
> any of those services, FCM included, is available.

Ian Lake seems to be from Google, https://medium.com/@ianhlake:

> Android Framework Developer at Google and Runner
> [www.google.com/+IanLake](http://www.google.com/+IanLake)